# Javascript function has 2 parameters but working even when taking 0 arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

How is this code working, isn't the staggerContainer function supposed to take two arguments? yet I see that it's given no arguments in the javascript code and it's fine, and if it's given nothing what is gonna be in the transition object for staggerContainer?

```css
export const staggerContainer = (staggerChildren, delayChildren) => ({
  hidden: {},
  show: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren,
      delayChildren,
    },
  },
});
```

```
const Explore = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('world-2');

  return (
    <section className={`${styles.paddings}`} id="explore">
      <motion.div
        variants={staggerContainer}
        initial="hidden"
        whileInView="show"
        viewport={{ once: false, amount: 0.25 }}
        className={`${styles.innerWidth} mx-auto flex flex-col`}
      >
        <TypingText title="| The World" textStyles="text-center" />
        <TitleText
          title={<>Choose the world you want <br className="md:block hidden" /> to explore</>}
          textStyles="text-center"
        />)
}

I see that in the javascript staggerContainer take 0 arguments and yet it's still working
```

Comment: You don't call `staggerContainer`, whatever `motion.div` is does. If it doesn't pass arguments they'd be undefined. If it does, it'll be whatever is passed. `staggerContainer` with no parens is a reference, `staggerContainer()` is a call.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters